# How do I toggle DOM classes in React (Material-UI)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [Material UI](https://material-ui.com) with React, I have a div:

```
<div className={classes.div}></div>
```

I want to add a conditional class to it:

```
<div className={classes.div + divActive ? `${classes.div}__active` : ''}></div>
```

The second example does not work - it always returns `<div class="makeStyles-div-2__active"></div>` where it should be:

divActive false: `<div class="makeStyles-div-2"></div>`

divActive true: `<div class="makeStyles-div-2 makeStyles-div-2__active"></div>`

What am I missing? I tried wrapping `classes.div` in extra template literal like:

`` <div className={`${classes.div}` + divActive ? `${classes.div}__active` : ''}></div> ``

But same results. When I remove the first class (`classes.div`) the `divActive` switch if seems to be working and toggles between active/inactive, so I guess my issue lies in the first variable, but what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the ternary condition in parenthesis & add some whitespace when `divActive` returns true

```
<div className={classes.div + (divActive ? ` ${classes.div}__active` : '')}></div>
```

Comment: Oh snap, I was thinking it's a Material UI issue, and I forgot about parenthesis, thank you :facepalm:. Will Accept your answer in 3 minutes, have a good day!

Comment: yes addition has precedence of `14` while ternary has `4`. grouping (parenthesis) has precedence of `21`